# How do I make the viewer zoom in programatically?

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I am writing an application using the Autodesk Viewer and I want to be able to programmatically set the camera's zoom level to be closer to my model. I am having trouble finding documentation on this.

I have tried something like this, which does not work.

```
setViewerZoomLevel(zoomLevel) {

    this.#viewer.impl.camera.zoom = zoomLevel
    this.#viewer.impl.invalidate(true);

}
```

Comment: Self update - I reached out via email to Autodesk and they confirmed that camera.zoom cannot be used as a zoom factor. They are looking in to alternate solutions. Will keep you all posted.

Comment: finally update: It is true APS viewer overrides the three.js camera, It is not surprise f it doesn’t work.  So basically, you have to scale yourself, instead of manipulating the scale factor of Three.js.  e.g. move camera position along the view direction to fit what zooming scale you expect to have.